# How to play tick sound of UIPickerView on iOS 10?

Tags: ios, audio, uipickerview, ios10, system-sounds

The title has it... There is a new sound on iOS 10 that `UIPickerView` plays each time the selected item is changed. Is there a way to play that sound? Ideally with `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_)` if there is system sound for it or in any other way if there is not any.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem and I finally found a solution

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(1157, nil);
```

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` will be deprecated in a future release. Use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion` instead.

If you want to mimic the sound and vibration of UIPickerView, you should also add the following code.

```
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
    UIImpactFeedbackGenerator *impactFeedBack = [[UIImpactFeedbackGenerator alloc] initWithStyle:UIImpactFeedbackStyleLight];
    [impactFeedBack prepare];
    [impactFeedBack impactOccurred];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use system click sounds or save them and use from local resources

```
//  NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/wheels_of_time.caf"]; // Too loud
//  NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/nano/TimerWheelHoursDetent_Haptic.caf"]; // Hours tick
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/nano/TimerWheelMinutesDetent_Haptic.caf"]; // Minutes tick
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)fileURL, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
```